# CGBitmapContextGetData returning nothing

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I want to get pixel information for the context

[image: Debugger display]

I don't know why every return is empty

Comment: You have tricked yourself. By declaring `bitmapData` as `char*`, the debugger treats it as as string. Since the first byte is obviously 0, the debugger displays it as an empty string. Everything is working as it should. It's probably better to use a different data type than `char*`.

Comment: And don't use `strlen()` and `printf("%c")`. It's not a string, it's not character data. The bitmap data is binary data.

Comment: CGBitmapContextGetData return  a void * pointer，Theoretically his size is 4 * pixelWidth * pixelHeight, now it seems that his space size is not right

Comment: Why do you think the size is not correct? Because of the difference in data types (`void*` vs `char*`)?

Comment: thank you,i should access to the address should not be get  the length of void *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot shows that the code is working fine but the data is treated as character data, which it is not.

Since the variable `bitmapData` is declared as `char*`, the debugger treats it as a null-terminated C string. It displays: `""`. This indicates that `bitmapData` is NOT null, but starts with a null character.

The raw pixel data is not a string, and not character data. So `strlen()` cannnot be used. And it's not possibly to display it with `printf("%c")`.

`bitmapData` is just a pointer to the raw bitmap data. Given `bitmapData`, it is not possible to derive the length of the data. The only safe way to query the length of the data is to call:

```
    int length = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context) * CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context);
```

Since you create a bitmap using 32 bits per pixel, I recommend to declare `bitmapData` as `uint32_t*`. Then each element in the array corresponds to a pixel.